# Stringtemplate - How to set date format to locale format

Tags: java, excel, date, date-format, stringtemplate-4

I'm processing Excel files with ExcelExplorer based on Stringtemplate4 (ST).
The files contain several columns with dates. 
By default, the dates are rendered following the "MM/dd/yy" date format.

Is there a way to render the dates as "dd/MM/yyyy"?

## I've tried it in several ways:

- I've tried defining it via the command line, without success.

  - Defining LC_ALL=fr_FR doesn't work.
  - Defining LC_TIME="dd/MM/yyyy" doesn't work. 
    See [Setting java locale settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64038/setting-java-locale-settings)
  - Calling java with the following command line options doesn't work.

java -Duser.language=fr -Duser.country=FR -Duser.variant=UTF-8 ...

## I've tried the following templates without success:

```
renderRow(row) ::= <<

<row.MyDate; format="dd/MM/yyyy"> 
>>
```

Although attribute MyDate is defined as a Date type, the above doesn't work.  I don't want to define MyDate as a Date type in Java as proposed in [Format date in String Template email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728623/format-date-in-string-template-email)

NB: After checking, I found out that ExcelExporter/ST defines attribute MyDate as a Date type!

## The following template doesn't work either :

```
renderRow(row; format="dd/MM/yyyy") ::= <<

<row.MyDate> 
>>
```

Comment: After reading the article in [Format date in String Template email] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2728623/format-date-in-string-template-email), the proper way to solve this is to add a property method in java while leaving the template **unchanged**.  This solution strictly maintains model-view separation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a renderer to your STGroup for each class you want to format:

```
    dir = STGroupDir(templateDirectory, '$', '$')
    dir.registerRenderer(Number.class, NumberRenderer())
    dir.registerRenderer(Date.class, DateRenderer())
```

Now, in my templates, I can use

`<row.MyDate; format="dd/MM/yyyy">` format string is used with `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`

or

`<row.MyNumber; format="%,d">`  format string is used with `java.util.Formatter`

If you need a custom formatter, take a look at the `DateRenderer`, it would be pretty straightforward to create your own.

Here's the documentation:

https://github.com/antlr/stringtemplate4/blob/master/doc/renderers.md